# Hlookup and Last Value In that Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find Excel Formula for the following:

I have a spreadsheet with weekly payroll cost. Row 1 is having various payment elements, including a column `Gross Pay`.

I have assigned `Wk_40` as named range to all the data.

On the summary sheet, I am using `HLOOKUP` formula to look for `Gross Pay`, and then for `row index number`, I want to select the last row of that column.

For example, Gross Pay is in column `M`, and Row # 427 is having a total of that column. In row # 430, I have done a pro-rata calculation, if the week is straddling across two months. I want to select amount from row # 430.

I tried

```
=hlookup($F$42,Wk_40,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307),false)
```

but this is returning `#N/A`.

Comment: If the answer helped you, could you please click on the checkmark outline? That's the conventional way to thank people here, instead of editing their answer :)

Comment: Hi Jerry, although I have clicked on the checkmark, but the  answer of my question was really in the comments. "=HLOOKUP("Gross Pay", WK_40,430,FALSE) which was in the answer, was not the answer I was looking for. The formula which resolved my issue was "=HLOOKUP("Gross Pay",Wk_40,MATCH(9^99,INDEX(Wk_40,0,MATCH("Gross Pay",INDEX(Wk_40,1,0),0))),0)", hence I replied in the comments. Thanks anyway, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems that you don't seem to understand how `HLOOKUP` works. Try using this:

```
=HLOOKUP("Gross Pay",Wk_40,430,FALSE)
```

This looks for `Gross Pay` in the named range (assuming that it covers from 1st row to at least the 430th row and has the column `Gross Pay` somewhere in the 1st row).

`430` is the row from which the required information is to be extracted.

Note:

- you can also use `0` instead of `FALSE`, since they mean the same thing in excel.
- I used `"Gross Pay"` in the formula because I'm not sure what `F42` contains (you didn't mention it at all in your question until the formula). If it has `Gross Pay`, then it should be working with `F42`.

---

If @simico understood correctly, then you could perhaps use `INDEX` and two `MATCH` to get the last value in the `Gross Pay` column:

```
=HLOOKUP("Gross Pay",Wk_40,MATCH(9^99,INDEX(Wk_40,0,MATCH("Gross Pay",INDEX(Wk_40,1,0),0))),0)
                           ^--------------------------------------------------------------^
```

`MATCH(0,INDEX(Wk_40,1,0),0)` gets the column number where `Gross Pay` is.

`INDEX(Wk_40,0,MATCH("Gross Pay",INDEX(Wk_40,1,0),0))` then returns the whole column.

`MATCH(9^99,INDEX(Wk_40,0,MATCH("Gross Pay",INDEX(Wk_40,1,0),0)))` then gives the last cell that contains a value.

Comment: Jerry, as I understood the Q, OP `want to select the last row of that column` and it's not always 430. That's why Op's used `MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307)`. Basically correct one should be `MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307, C:C)` where C:C is the column, with `Gross Pay`, but the problem is to determin column address

Comment: Jerry, `MATCH("Gross Pay",1:1,0)` gives you column number starting from first column, e.g. if `"Gross Pay"` in column `I`, it would give you `9`. Now, if `Wk_40` say `G1:I7`, `INDEX(Wk_40,0,MATCH("Gross Pay",1:1,0))` would evaluates to `INDEX(G1:I7,0,9)` and gives you #REF, since `G1:I7` hasn't 9th column..

Comment: Yup, it's true, in my example `G1:I7` contains `Gross Pay` (column `I`), because I sad `if "Gross Pay" in column I`..but the problem is that you counts column of `Gross Pay` starting from column `A`, but your `Wk_40` not necessarily starts from column A

Comment: see [example image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p6d6e9p2eot7ky/test.png). My `Wk_40` defined as `G1:I7`, and `MATCH("Gross Pay",1:1,0)` returns 9, but `Wk_40` has only 3 columns

Comment: @simoco is 100% right and you dont even know if Wk_40 start in the first worksheet row

Comment: @Jarry, as I see you should make last small edit: change `INDEX(Wk_40,1)` to `INDEX(Wk_40,1,0)`:)

Comment: it gives me `#REF` but with `INDEX(Wk_40,1,0)` gives correct result:)

Comment: and change it also in the formula itself:)

Comment: It is only optional if range contains only one column

Answer (score 1):

WIth this you get the correct row number in the correct column...then with index and a very big formula later you get the result:

```
=MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307;INDEX(Wk_40;0;MATCH("Gross Pay";INDEX(Wk_40;1;0);0));1)
```

Like this:

```
=INDEX(Wk_40;MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307;INDEX(Wk_40;0;MATCH("Gross Pay";INDEX(Wk_40;1;0);0));1);MATCH("Gross Pay";INDEX(Wk_40;1;0)))
```

Assuming that Wk_40 contains all the data and the first row of Wk_40 contains headers where you can find "Gross Pay". And, of course, besides the header you only have numeric values.